# Tkinter Text Box (Randomly/Alternatively Change Foreground Color of text box of Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#Text Frame

TextFrame = Frame(win, bg="#003030")
TextFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

#Create a Text Box

TextBox = Text(TextFrame)
TextBox.pack(side="bottom", fill=BOTH, expand=True)

#Color Picker
choose = ["#ff0000", "#0000ff"]

color = choice(choose)

#Button Function

def render():
    global color
    from tkinter import Text
    input = (TextBox.get("1.0",'end-1c')) #Takes input from the Text Box
    win2 = Toplevel()
    win2.attributes("-fullscreen", True)


    TextFull = Text(win2, font="Ubuntu 14",**fg=choice(choose)**, bg="black")
    TextFull.insert(0.0,input) #Displays Input from first window to second window
    TextFull.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

How do I get random fg color from the choose list alternatively in the text box. Currently I am only getting one fg color at a time.

Comment: Are you wanting to alternate colors on each line?

Comment: "Hi Thanks for the reply"

In the above sentence I want to randomly or alternatively assign BLUE & RED Color to the words. To each words.

Comment: Oh, so each _word_, not each _line_?

Comment: Yes precisely . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #Color Picker
colorlist = ["#ff0000", "#0000ff"]

#Button Function

def render():
    global color
    import random
    from tkinter import Text
    input = (TextBox.get("1.0",'end-1c')) #Takes input from the Text Box
    win2 = Toplevel()
    win2.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

    TextFull = Text(win2,
        font="Ubuntu 14",
        fg="white",
        bg="black")

    for i in range (len(colorlist)):
        TextFull.tag_configure(str(i), foreground=colorlist[i])

    # TextFull.insert(0.0,input) #Displays Input from first window to second window
    TextFull.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    for i in input:
        tempchoice =random.randint(0, len(colorlist)-1)
        TextFull.insert(END, i, str(tempchoice))
    TextFull.insert(END, '\n')
```

I finally managed to get the desired result by using tag_configure. Not random words but letters and I am okay with it. Thanks to Melvin Chia for answering the solution of this problem on the Tkinter Facebook Group.

Answer (score 0):

First you must create the Text widget with an initial foreground color. Then you need to change the color of the foreground in a timed matter. You can use the `after()` method for that:

```
def render():

    def flash():                                            # <-- flash()
        TextFull.config(fg=choice(["#ff0000", "#0000ff"]))  # <-- update color
        win.after(1000, flash)                              # <-- call flash again after 1 second

    global color
    from tkinter import Text
    input = (TextBox.get("1.0",'end-1c')) #Takes input from the Text Box
    win2 = Toplevel()
    win2.attributes("-fullscreen", True)


    TextFull = Text(win2, font="Ubuntu 14", fg='#0000ff', bg="black")
    TextFull.insert(0.0,input) #Displays Input from first window to second window
    TextFull.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    flash()                                                   # call flash
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

This did change the color but it changed the color of the whole sentence and not each words randomly.

Comment: That's how I understood your question and also how you presented your code. Changing the color of each word separately is much more complex and not easy to answer at all. But you can use the technique along with some other techniques to accomplish that.